# How do I write a flow annotation that specifies something is an object?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do I write a [flow](/questions/tagged/flow) annotation that specifies that an argument must be an object, not `null`, a string, a number, etc?

For example:

```
const foo = (x : ?) : string => {
  return JSON.stringify(x);
};
```

I want to design my annotations such that:

```
foo({}); // Passes
foo({ x: 1 }); // Passes
foo({ xs: [ 1, 2, 3 ], y: 'abc' }); // Passes

foo(null); // Fails
foo(undefined); // Fails
foo('abc'); // Fails
foo(123); // Fails
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/

Comment: @FelixKling Yes I did, but I did not see an example of what I am after. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: An unsealed object should work: `(x : {}): string => { ... }`.

Comment: `Object` will work as well: `const foo = (x: Object) : string => { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inexact object should do the trick if you're looking to allow passing objects with extra properties. As @Felix Kling stated:

```
const foo = (x: {}): string => {
```

should do. This is due to [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) where `{}` is basically the narrowest you can get.